# Are source and sink part of system or are they part of the surroundings?

Tags: thermodynamics

This question is regarding the interactions of a thermodynamic system with its environment: do we count the sources and sinks of entropy (heat) as part of the thermodynamic system or as part of the environment?

For example, say, we have a gas inside a cylinder, and also inside the cylinder we have a battery and attached to it is a resistor heating (Joule heating, $\dot q =I^2R$) the gas. The cylinder itself is in both thermal and, through a piston, in mechanical interaction with its environment.

Is the battery + resistor a part of the environment of the cylinder + gas system or is it a part of the cylinder + gas that we call the thermodynamic system?

Comment: Pleas elaborate your question what "source and sink " are you talking about? What system?

Comment: It seems clear to me what the OP is asking and should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are asking what constitutes the "system" and what constitutes the "surroundings" (environment).

The system is anything (object, substance, region in space, etc.) you want to study. Once defined, everything not included in the system becomes the surroundings, with the combination of the system and surroundings constituting the so called “universe”.

Delineating the system from its surroundings are its boundaries. Those boundaries can be real or imaginary, movable or fixed, open or closed, diathermic or adiabatic. The nature of the boundaries determines what can and cannot transfer (mass, energy) between the system and its surroundings.

That said, for your  battery + resistor example, the battery and/or resistor can be defined as part of the system or as part of the surroundings, as long as the boundaries between the system and surroundings are clearly defined. It really depends on what you want to study, which then should be part of the system. The same would apply to heat sources and sinks.

The important thing to keep in mind is whatever it is you want to study should be included in your definition of the system, and that the study generally consists of an analysis of the transfer of mass and/or of energy in the form of heat and/or work, between the system and the surroundings.

Hope this helps.